# pipenv fails to install packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pycharm, pipenv

I want to install the following packages in a pipenv for a facial recognition app. The installation process fails with almost all of these packages.

The only packages that did install correctly were opencv-python and numpy

- cmake
- face-recognition
- numpy
- dlib
- opencv-python

I already searched other stackoverflow posts and none of them seemed to help.

Error output:

```
(SecureCam) C:\dev\python\SecureCam>pipenv install dlib
Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, so it will automatically use that environment, instead of creating its own for any project. You can set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment and create its own instead. You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to
 suppress this warning.
Installing dlib…
Adding dlib to Pipfile's [packages]…
Installation Succeeded
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (d62603)…
An error occurred while installing dlib==19.19.0 --hash=sha256:d0eeaca07bc4c75973ad0f739a541d8fa4003af778f0dc1c2c595d470823819a! Will try again.
  ================================ 4/4 - 00:00:05
Installing initially failed dependencies…
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\users\thealphakarp\.virtualenvs\securecam-pkqbmejs\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 1983, in do_install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       do_init(
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\users\thealphakarp\.virtualenvs\securecam-pkqbmejs\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 1246, in do_init
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       do_install_dependencies(
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\users\thealphakarp\.virtualenvs\securecam-pkqbmejs\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 858, in do_install_dependencies
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       batch_install(
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\users\thealphakarp\.virtualenvs\securecam-pkqbmejs\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 763, in batch_install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       _cleanup_procs(procs, not blocking, failed_deps_queue, retry=retry)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\users\thealphakarp\.virtualenvs\securecam-pkqbmejs\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 681, in _cleanup_procs
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       raise exceptions.InstallError(c.dep.name, extra=err_lines)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['Collecting dlib==19.19.0 (from -r C:\\Users\\THEALP~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pipenv-imqiansg-requirements\\pipenv-08m7x4g7-requirement.txt (line 1))', '  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/63/92/05c3b98636661cb80d190a5a777dd94effcc14c0f6893222e5ca81e74fbc/dl
ib-19.19.0.tar.gz', 'Building wheels for collected packages: dlib', '  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for dlib: started', "  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for dlib: finished with status 'error'", '  Complete output from command c:\\users\\thealphakarp\\.virtualenvs\\securecam-pkqbmejs\\scripts\\python.exe -u -c "i
mport setuptools, tokenize;__file__=\'C:\\\\Users\\\\TheAlphaKarp\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\pip-install-7ilrv6cx\\\\dlib\\\\setup.py\';f=getattr(tokenize, \'open\', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace(\'\\r\\n\', \'\\n\');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, \'exec\'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\\Users\\TheAlp
haKarp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-4ikt0xup --python-tag cp38:', '  running bdist_wheel', '  running build', '  running build_py', "  package init file 'dlib\\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)", '  warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.', '  ', '  running build_ext', '  Build
ing extension for Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 23:03:10) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]', "  Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\\Users\\TheAlphaKarp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7ilrv6cx\\dlib\\tools\\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\TheAlphaKarp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-i
nstall-7ilrv6cx\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\thealphakarp\\.virtualenvs\\securecam-pkqbmejs\\scripts\\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\TheAlphaKarp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7ilrv6cx\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -A x64'", '  -- Building
 for: NMake Makefiles', '  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):', '    Generator', '  ', '      NMake Makefiles', '  ', '    does not support platform specification, but platform', '  ', '      x64', '  ', '    was specified.', '  ', '  ', '  CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage', '
  CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage', '  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!', '  See also "C:/Users/TheAlphaKarp/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-7ilrv6cx/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-3.8/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".', '  Traceback (most recent call last):', '    File "<s
tring>", line 1, in <module>', '    File "C:\\Users\\TheAlphaKarp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7ilrv6cx\\dlib\\setup.py", line 223, in <module>', '      setup(', '    File "c:\\users\\thealphakarp\\.virtualenvs\\securecam-pkqbmejs\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools\\__init__.py", line 144, in setup', '
return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)', '    File "c:\\users\\thealphakarp\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\distutils\\core.py", line 148, in setup', '      dist.run_commands()', '    File "c:\\users\\thealphakarp\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\distutils\\dist.py", line 966, i
n run_commands', '      self.run_command(cmd)', '    File "c:\\users\\thealphakarp\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\distutils\\dist.py", line 985, in run_command', '      cmd_obj.run()', '    File "c:\\users\\thealphakarp\\.virtualenvs\\securecam-pkqbmejs\\lib\\site-packages\\wheel\\bdist_wheel
.py", line 223, in run', "      self.run_command('build')", '    File "c:\\users\\thealphakarp\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\distutils\\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command', '      self.distribution.run_command(command)', '    File "c:\\users\\thealphakarp\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\py
thon38\\lib\\distutils\\dist.py", line 985, in run_command', '      cmd_obj.run()', '    File "c:\\users\\thealphakarp\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\distutils\\command\\build.py", line 135, in run', '      self.run_command(cmd_name)', '    File "c:\\users\\thealphakarp\\appdata\\local\\progr
ams\\python\\python38\\lib\\distutils\\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command', '      self.distribution.run_command(command)', '    File "c:\\users\\thealphakarp\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\distutils\\dist.py", line 985, in run_command', '      cmd_obj.run()', '    File "C:\\Users\\TheAlphaKar
p\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7ilrv6cx\\dlib\\setup.py", line 135, in run', '      self.build_extension(ext)', '    File "C:\\Users\\TheAlphaKarp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7ilrv6cx\\dlib\\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension', '      subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)', '
 File "c:\\users\\thealphakarp\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call', '      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)', "  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\\\Users\\\\TheAlphaKarp\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\pip-install-7ilrv6cx\\\\dlib
\\\\tools\\\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\\\Users\\\\TheAlphaKarp\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\pip-install-7ilrv6cx\\\\dlib\\\\build\\\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\\\users\\\\thealphakarp\\\\.virtualenvs\\\\securecam-pkqbmejs\\\\scripts\\\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPU
T_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\\\Users\\\\TheAlphaKarp\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\pip-install-7ilrv6cx\\\\dlib\\\\build\\\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.", '  ', '  ----------------------------------------', '  Running setup.py clean for dlib', 'Failed to build dlib', 'Installin
g collected packages: dlib', '  Running setup.py install for dlib: started', "    Running setup.py install for dlib: finished with status 'error'", '    Complete output from command c:\\users\\thealphakarp\\.virtualenvs\\securecam-pkqbmejs\\scripts\\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__=\'C:\\\
\Users\\\\TheAlphaKarp\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\pip-install-7ilrv6cx\\\\dlib\\\\setup.py\';f=getattr(tokenize, \'open\', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace(\'\\r\\n\', \'\\n\');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, \'exec\'))" install --record C:\\Users\\TheAlphaKarp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-record-
fbfltxrc\\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\\users\\thealphakarp\\.virtualenvs\\securecam-pkqbmejs\\include\\site\\python3.8\\dlib:', '    running install', '    running build', '    running build_py', "    package init file 'dlib\\__init__.py' not found (or n
ot a regular file)", '    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.', '    ', '    running build_ext', '    Building extension for Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 23:03:10) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]', "    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\\Users\\TheAlphaKarp\\AppData\\Local\\Tem
p\\pip-install-7ilrv6cx\\dlib\\tools\\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\TheAlphaKarp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7ilrv6cx\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\thealphakarp\\.virtualenvs\\securecam-pkqbmejs\\scripts\\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RE
LEASE=C:\\Users\\TheAlphaKarp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7ilrv6cx\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -A x64'", '    -- Building for: NMake Makefiles', '    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):', '      Generator', '    ', '        NMake Makefiles', '    ', '      does not support platform specificati
on, but platform', '    ', '        x64', '    ', '      was specified.', '    ', '    ', '    CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage', '    CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage', '    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!', '    See also "C:/Users/TheAlphaKar
p/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-7ilrv6cx/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-3.8/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".', '    Traceback (most recent call last):', '      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>', '      File "C:\\Users\\TheAlphaKarp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7ilrv6cx\\dlib\\setup.py", line 223, in <
module>', '        setup(', '      File "c:\\users\\thealphakarp\\.virtualenvs\\securecam-pkqbmejs\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools\\__init__.py", line 144, in setup', '        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)', '      File "c:\\users\\thealphakarp\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\distutils\
\core.py", line 148, in setup', '        dist.run_commands()', '      File "c:\\users\\thealphakarp\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\distutils\\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands', '        self.run_command(cmd)', '      File "c:\\users\\thealphakarp\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38
\\lib\\distutils\\dist.py", line 985, in run_command', '        cmd_obj.run()', '      File "c:\\users\\thealphakarp\\.virtualenvs\\securecam-pkqbmejs\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools\\command\\install.py", line 61, in run', '        return orig.install.run(self)', '      File "c:\\users\\thealphakarp\\appdata\\
local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\distutils\\command\\install.py", line 545, in run', "        self.run_command('build')", '      File "c:\\users\\thealphakarp\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\distutils\\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command', '        self.distribution.run_command(command)',
 '      File "c:\\users\\thealphakarp\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\distutils\\dist.py", line 985, in run_command', '        cmd_obj.run()', '      File "c:\\users\\thealphakarp\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\distutils\\command\\build.py", line 135, in run', '        self.
run_command(cmd_name)', '      File "c:\\users\\thealphakarp\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\distutils\\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command', '        self.distribution.run_command(command)', '      File "c:\\users\\thealphakarp\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\distutils\\dist.p
y", line 985, in run_command', '        cmd_obj.run()', '      File "C:\\Users\\TheAlphaKarp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7ilrv6cx\\dlib\\setup.py", line 135, in run', '        self.build_extension(ext)', '      File "C:\\Users\\TheAlphaKarp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7ilrv6cx\\dlib\\setup.py", li
ne 172, in build_extension', '        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)', '      File "c:\\users\\thealphakarp\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call', '        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)', "    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Comm
and '['cmake', 'C:\\\\Users\\\\TheAlphaKarp\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\pip-install-7ilrv6cx\\\\dlib\\\\tools\\\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\\\Users\\\\TheAlphaKarp\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\pip-install-7ilrv6cx\\\\dlib\\\\build\\\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\\\users\
\\\thealphakarp\\\\.virtualenvs\\\\securecam-pkqbmejs\\\\scripts\\\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\\\Users\\\\TheAlphaKarp\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\pip-install-7ilrv6cx\\\\dlib\\\\build\\\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.", '    ', '    -------
---------------------------------']
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['Failed building wheel for dlib', 'Command "c:\\users\\thealphakarp\\.virtualenvs\\securecam-pkqbmejs\\scripts\\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__=\'C:\\\\Users\\\\TheAlphaKarp\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\pip-install-7ilrv6cx\\\\dlib\\\\setup.py\';f=geta
ttr(tokenize, \'open\', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace(\'\\r\\n\', \'\\n\');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, \'exec\'))" install --record C:\\Users\\TheAlphaKarp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-record-fbfltxrc\\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\\users\
\thealphakarp\\.virtualenvs\\securecam-pkqbmejs\\include\\site\\python3.8\\dlib" failed with error code 1 in C:\\Users\\TheAlphaKarp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7ilrv6cx\\dlib\\']
ERROR: ERROR: Package installation failed...
     ================================ 0/1 - 00:00:05
```

Editor: PyCharm 2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the visual studio community c++ development build-tools and restart your computer.

reference video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D5xqcGk6LEc

Answer (score 1):

In your **PyCharm** go to `File -> settings -> Project:test(test means your project name) -> select project interpretor -> click add button`

[image]

After clicking add button and **search** your libraries and click install. Do this for by one library by one.

- `cmake`
- `face-recognition`
- `numpy`
- `dlib`
- `opencv-python`

---

## Update

For the c++ development build-tools issue I have already discussed in this site. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61561150/11383441) answer to fix c++ development build-tools issue.

Comment: That didn't solve it, The problem was that I needed to install the c++ development build-tools.

Comment: In your error there is no evidence of requiring c++ development build-tools. And also I have successfully installed all that libraries without installing that. Even though I haven't installed visual studio also. But I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

i was having issues with it before but i got it sorted out by installing my packages through anaconda prompt