# Scrapy Installation (Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required)

Tags: python, cmd, pip, scrapy

I have been trying to install scrapy for days now through the command, `pip install scrapy`.

After downloading the requirements, I am getting this error code.

> ```
> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
>     ----------------------------------------
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\pancore builders\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\PANCORE BUILDERS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h2e9etct\\Twisted\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\PANCORE BUILDERS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h2e9etct\\Twisted\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\PANCORE BUILDERS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-3qfphtaw\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\pancore builders\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\Twisted' Check the logs for full command output.
> ```

I read about installing Visual Code by Microsoft, but even then it is still not working for me.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Download Microsoft Visual C++ Build tools through this [link](https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/f/7/5f7acaeb-8363-451f-9425-68a90f98b238/visualcppbuildtools_full.exe?fixForIE=.exe). Then try to install `scrapy` again.

Comment: There are binary packages for windows https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2881

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says everything. You have to download **Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools** for get rid of from this error. You can download this from [here](https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/f/7/5f7acaeb-8363-451f-9425-68a90f98b238/visualcppbuildtools_full.exe?fixForIE=.exe). There is no need to download visual studio for this.

After the installation, you must restart your system. After that you can install your library.

If you are using python3.x version, run this code

```
pip3 install scrapy
```

If you are using python2.x version, run this code

```
pip install scrapy
```

Answer (score 1):

According to scrapy docs [recommended](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#windows) way install scrapy on windows and the only reliable way to avoid issues with pip intalled scrapy - usage of conda python distribution

Installing Microsoft Visual C++ Build tools - doens't guarantee that It solve this issues (works differently depending on windows version, and version of Microsoft Visual C++)