# Unable to install Kivy. Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, kivy

I have problem with Kivy installation.
After installation attempt, I'm receiving error.

Log content:

```
[INFO   ] Logger: Record log in C:\Users\Moff\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-05-03_3.txt
[INFO   ] deps: Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] deps: Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] deps: Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] deps: Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] Kivy: v2.0.0rc2, git-Unknown, 20200503
[INFO   ] Kivy: Installed at "C:\Users\Moff\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-x_c9hiwi\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] Python: v3.8.3rc1 (tags/v3.8.3rc1:802eb67, Apr 29 2020, 21:39:14) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] Python: Interpreter at "C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe"
[WARNING] stderr: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

I think, error points lack of C++, but I have it installed.

I'm trying to install Kivy by command:

```
python -m pip install --no-use-pep517 https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip
```

I don't know how to overpass this problem.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Did you follow the dependency instructions on kivy.org?

Comment: I have to admit that I didn't checked kivy.org installation guide.

I've downgraded Python from 3.8.3 to 3.7.6 and it looks ok.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Follow this [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61561150/11383441) and tell me the progress.